# How to Spam protect my Typo3 v8 website

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

How can i protect my email adresses in my Typo3 website v8.

Usually in older version i find this :

```
config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = 2

config.spamProtectEmailAddresses_atSubst = (at)
```

but this is didn't work, what i'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me with TYPO3 8.7.1.

```
config.spamProtectEmailAddresses = 1
config.spamProtectEmailAddresses_atSubst = (at)
```

Please make sure that there is no space between the colon and the email address.

```
<a href="mailto:info@my_company.org">Mail</a>
```

Comment: This works for regular text, but not for fe_user email fields, do i forgot to change something ?

Comment: Not working at my typo3 8.7.7 :(. The replacement of the at sign is working, but the email is not linked. Any idea?